# What are the most widely used open source DAO frameworks?

Tags: solidity, web3js, multisignature, dao, governance

I am currently researching what are the best open-source on-chain **Governance Tools** out there (for beginners / intermediates).

I was researching something similar in 2016 / 2017 but I remember the technology was very immature back then, as in, not enough security audits ( see **[The DAO](https://www.coindesk.com/learn/2016/06/25/understanding-the-dao-attack/)** ) or advanced lack of GUIs.

What are the current open sourced tools / frameworks for creating and governing DAOs today in 2022?

Everybody is talking about **[Gnosis.io](https://gnosis.io/)**. Is Gnosis any good? Are there any alternatives to Gnosis?

Answer (score 0):

Not in a particular order

- [Snapshop](https://snapshot.org/) is a popular tool for governance voting
- [Aragon](https://aragon.org/) is an old project that provides tools for DAO governance
- Gnosis Safe is a multi-signature wallet, not a governance tool, though they have [SafeSnap integration for DAO governance](https://blog.gnosis.pm/introducing-safesnap-the-first-in-a-decentralized-governance-tool-suite-for-the-gnosis-safe-ea67eb95c34f?gi=888f82bce314)
- [Kleros](https://kleros.io/) is arbitration as a service for DAOs
- [Enzyme Protocol](https://enzyme.finance/) can be used to provide treasury management services for DAOs
- [Sputnik DAO](https://github.com/near-daos/sputnik-dao-contract) provides DAO governance features on NEAR blockchain
- [LiquiFi](https://www.liquifi.finance/) provides token vesting schedules for DAO members like founders
- [DAO-Analyzer](https://github.com/Grasia/dao-analyzer) can be used to track DAO metrics
- [DAOHaus](https://app.daohaus.club/explore) offers DAO exploration and discovery tools
- [Gitcoin](https://gitcoin.co/) offers co-ordination with open source developers and bounties
- [Immunefi](https://immunefi.com/) is a bounty platform for security researches and whitehats to get rewarded for discover problems in smart contracts

Answer (score 0):

On top of the excellent list Mikko Ohtamaa already shared, I would add the following:

- [Tally](https://tally.xyz) is an on-chain alternative to [Snapshot](https://snapshot.org)
- [Coordinape](https://coordinape.com) can be used to efficiently reward a large number of contributors
- [Sablier](https://sablier.com) enables token streaming, which is ideal for on-chain vesting/payroll/grants (disclosure: I'm part of the team)

Highly recommend checking out [DAO Masters](https://daomasters.xyz) if you want to look into other projects/tools related to DAOs/governance.